# Print current base language in tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I statically added a link to /cart on the *page.tpl.php* template file. Since it's a multi language website, the link doesn't always work.

How do I print a link that consider the currently used language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to display the cart link in a template you better do it with [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) or [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7).

```html
<ul>
<li><?php print l(t('Cart', 'cart')) ?></li>
<li><a href="<?php print url('cart') ?>">Cart</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work in your page.tpl.php

```
global $language;
global $base_url;
//get the current language
$current_lang = $language->language;
//get the default language
$default_language = language_default();

switch($current_lang) {
  case($default_language):
    $url = $base_url."/cart";
    break;
  default:
    $url = $base_url."/". $current_lang ."/cart";
}
```

I added the `language_default()` part as per Clive suggestion. You'll find more information on [`global $language`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/language/7).

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to print "en" or "nl" somewhere, depending on the current language:

```
<?php
  global $language ;
  $curlang = $language->language;
?>

This is the prefix of the current language: <?php print $curlang; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

cptstarling is correct. I was getting error's back from SEO reports asking for Language declarations, and simply created a custom HTML.tpl.php theme template that included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="<?php echo $language->language; ?>">
```

I did not declare a variable, as this was the only location that I needed the PHP language to be displayed.